# Mac Citrix Workspace I can't write curly braces using an ITA keybaord

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, citrix

I've just bought a Macbook Air 2020 (Apple Silicon) with an Italian keyboard.
I work in the game dev industry and in our company, we use Citrix Workspace to use remote PCs.
After setting up the connection with my IT manager I've started trying Citrix Workspace and soon I've realized that the Mac version of Citrix is really buggy.
The curly braces do not work using any keyboard language on the mac/remote PC.
I've tried every possible setting in Citrix Workspace but nothing seems to have an effect.

Comment: I can't see where curly braces are on an Italian keyboard, but have you tried the same physical locations as on an English keyboard? That's Shift & the two keys right of P - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdZzH.png - sometimes remote apps keep 'positions' rather than actual equivalents for things like this. [I can't test on Italian, but Citrix remoting to Windows from Mac on a UK keyboard works using the keys as printed].

Comment: On the Ita keyboard, the curly braces are typed using SHIFT + ALT + "specific key".
I've tried changing the keyboard language on the MAC and on the remote PC with no success.
I've tested the keyboard locally and remotely and seems that Citrix completely cancels every ALT (option) input.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I've tried that but doesn't work